# How to prevent automatic render when state changed by some other component that uses React Context API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm using react with Context API. In the context i have a property called isAuthenticated and that property is used in App.js For routing purpose. But the problem is, When the isAuthenticated property is manipulated, That App.js file also re-renders. And i don't want that behavior .

How to prevent that automatic re-render of component even when that data changes or state changes by other component.

I think React.memo is the option i have, Is it correct solution?

My routing config:

```
  <HashRouter>
   <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/app/dashboard" />} />
     <Route
       exact
       path="/app"
       render={() => <Redirect to="/app/dashboard" />}
     />
     <PrivateRoute path="/app" component={Layout} />
     <PublicRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
     <Route component={Error} />
   </Switch>
 </HashRouter>
```

Public and private route based on isAuthenticated value that coming from Context api

```
  function PrivateRoute({ component, ...rest }) {
  console.log(isAuthenticated)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          React.createElement(component, props)
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: {
                from: props.location,
              },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

function PublicRoute({ component, ...rest }) {
  console.log(isAuthenticated)
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/",
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          React.createElement(component, props)
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preventing component render after state changes are not good approaches because this situation is not fit logic of React environment.

I think you should change the application business logic. I suggest you check the [Atomic Design Methodology](http://atomicdesign.bradfrost.com/).

Comment: Yaeh ok, but how can I control the situation.

Comment: Can you share your more code or your project via github or something else?

Comment: That is in butbucket repo

Comment: Sorry but I can't expressing an opinion without see the code anymore.